# ¿Cómo evita hacer doble llamada a la base de datos en django?

Tags: python, django

Tengo dos modelos, uno llamado Ticket y otro TicketDetail:

```
class Ticket(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(editable=True)
    seller = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % self.id

class TicketDetail(models.Model):
    ticket = models.ForeignKey(Ticket, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cartridge = models.ForeignKey(Cartridge, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    price = models.DecimalField(default=0, max_digits=12, decimal_places=2)
```

¿Habrá una forma de hacer un llamado a la base de datos y traer esos ds modelos juntos?

He leído un poco de `prefetch_related_objects()` pero estoy totalmente perdido, no sé para qué se utiliza, espero me puedan explicar para que es este método que me recomendaron y cómo usarlo, no sé si ayude a resolver mi problema.

Anexo información del método en el modelo de Ticket:

```
def total(self):
    tickets_details = TicketDetail.objects.filter(ticket=self.id)
    total = 0
    for x in tickets_details:
        total += x.price
    return total
```

Y esto es en el admin:

```
@admin.register(Ticket)
class TicketAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'created_at', 'seller', 'ticket_details', 'payment_type', 'total')
    list_filter = ('seller', 'created_at', 'payment_type')
    list_display_links = ('id', 'created_at')
    date_hierarchy = 'created_at'
    inlines = [TicketDetailInline, ]
```

El método para conseguir los totales, ¿Cómo seŕia la forma adecuada de usar la copia en la memoria?

¡Gracias!

Comment: ¿Quieres hacer un join de esas tablas?

Comment: ¿Podría decirse, habrá algún metodo que incorpore django? o ¿tendría que hacerlo manualmente?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bueno, en Django, hacer un Join de tablas es fácil, tienes dos formas para hacerlo de acuerdo a la relación de tus modelos y el QuerySet que vayas a implementar.

La primera forma es con **select_related(*args)**:

```
# para esta forma, solo aplica a relaciones con ForeingKey
# en tu caso
TicketDetail.objects.all().select_related('ticket')
```

Puedes ver el código en sql que fue ejecutado, si a la sentencia le das print, de esta forma: `print(TicketDetail.objects.all().select_related('ticket').query)`, y verás como django hace un LEFT OUTER JOIN con la tabla ticket, esto es muy importante sobretodo cuando hablas de optimización, muchas veces no nos preocupamos por eso pero lo que hacemos es realizar muchas llamadas a la base de datos sin sentido.

En el caso de relaciones de muchos a muchos, o la inversa de la llave foránea que seria de muchos a uno, cambia un poco la forma de hacerlo, ahora dispones de un método llamado **prefetch_related(*args)**:

```
# Aplica a relaciones de tipo ManyToMany.
# en tu caso
Ticket.objects.all().prefetch_related('ticketdetail_set')
```

Al hacerlo de esta forma e intentar mirar el query en sql que ejecutó, vemos que es el mismo a como si no le pasaras el `prefetch_related`, y es porque django lo que hace, es una copia de la relación en el cache y trabajar sobre ella, de modo que es una ayuda pero solo siempre y cuando sepas usarla a conveniencia. Te explico...

```
# muchas veces hacemos cosas como estas
tickets = Ticket.objects.all().prefetch_related('ticketdetail_set')
for ticket in tickets:
    if ticket.ticketdetail_set.filter(quantity__gt=0).exists():
        # do something
```

Y resulta que al hacer un filter de ticketdetail, dejamos de trabajar sobre la copia en cache que django hizo al momento de pasar el prefetch_related. Ya que Django hace la copia con un ticket.ticketdetail_set.all(), entonces hay que saber usarlo, no sea que estemos implementando mas consultas de las que queremos.

**EDICIÓN**

Para hacer la consulta que quieres de acuerdo al total, debes hacer un `annotate()` (anotación), de la siguiente manera:

```
tickets = Ticket.objects.all().prefetch_related('ticketdetail_set').annotate(total_ticket=models.Sum('ticketdetail_set__price'))

# Luego al recorrer, lo haces normal, pero ahora tu objeto tiene un atributo tota_ticket, el cual hará lo mismo que haces ahora en tu método total, evitando hacer muchas consultas, ahora solo haces una.
for ticket in tickets:
    assert ticket.total_ticket == ticket.total()
```

Cualquier pregunta amigo, comenta.

Comment: Tengo un método en el modelo Ticket para que me despliegue el total, hice una función parecida a la que mencionas, pero supongo que estoy haciendo algo malo, de acuerdo a lo que me comentas... cómo podría evitar las llamadas que hago en cada iteración? ... Anexo el código en la pregunta.

Comment: @RamsésMartínezOrtiz listo amigo, edité la pregunta.